# When can be played broken MPEG-4 file

Tags: mpeg, mpeg-4

MPEG-4 file is transmitted via satellite and can be broken. How many errors can contain file and in which places so that I can play it?

Comment: First, this is off-topic here. Second, there is [almost] no redundancy in the file, so no errors allowed.

Comment: I am not sure if your question is on-topic here. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. However, your question *is* interesting in general. You may try to reword it in the meaning of http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, or try to find one of the many http://stackexchange.com/sites which might be more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, an MPEG-4 file (.mp4) has a metadata section (relatively very small) and a media data section.

In `Progressive mp4` format, the metadata section comes first. So user can start play while downloading remaining data.

This metadata contains audio/video frame information that are essentially byte offset and length. So overall file structure must be maintained (that is the same size).

Check this post for more details:
[Understanding the MPEG-4 movie atom](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/video/articles/mp4_movie_atom.html)